# How to run dynamically loaded js file in iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var myIframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
  var element = myIframe.contentDocument.createElement('script');  
  element.setAttribute('src', '/javascripts/library/jquery/jquery.min.js');  
  myIframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(element);

  $('#myIframe', top.document).load(function() {
    alert('iframe has loaded');

    var element = document.getElementById('myIframe').contentDocument.createElement('script');  
    element.setAttribute('src', '/javascripts/stuff.js');  
    myIframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(element);  
  });

});
```

I get an alert of "iframe has loaded."

stuff.js contains

```
$('body').css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
```

So, I would expect that the iframe's background color would change to yellow when the iframe has loaded...but nothing happens. I even tried surround what's in stuff.js in a $(document).ready block but had the same results.

If I select all and view source for the iframe, I see that jquery.min.js and stuff.js are in the iframe's . If I put this source output into a separate html file and run that, the document's background color changes as expected.

How can I get my javascript in stuff.js to run in the iframe once the iframe has loaded?

Comment: Do you get any script errors?  Did you try an `alert` in stuff.js?  Did you check Firebug?

Comment: No script errors, and no alert. I'll snoop around with Firebug after I get back from the store.

Comment: I don't see anything strange when looking at it with Firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hell yeah, I figured it out!

Turns out it was not working because I had set myIframe.contentDocument.designMode to "on". Commenting that out made it work. Hopefully I can turn it on after stuff.js has loaded and all will be well.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in a more jQuery way.

```
$('<script/>', {
    src: '/path/to/javascript.js',
    type: 'text/javascript'
}).appendTo($('#iframe').contents().find('body'));
```